# How to see the green check mark mentioned in man snap?

Tags: gnome-terminal, snap, 19.04, unicode

OS: Ubuntu 19.04

Both the *list* and *find* commands in `man snap` have this:

> A green check mark (given color and unicode support) after a publisher
>   name indicates that the publisher has been verified.

However, when I run `snap list`, I don't see any check marks against *Canonical* or *kde*; instead I see green asterisks:

[image: Green asterisks]

Does this mean that gnome-terminal doesn't have unicode support? But I can use U+237B (⍻) and U+2718 (✘), etc in gnome-terminal.

Is there something else I need to do?

---

```
dkb: ~ $ locale
LANG=en_IN
LANGUAGE=en_IN:en
LC_CTYPE="en_IN"
LC_NUMERIC="en_IN"
LC_TIME="en_IN"
LC_COLLATE="en_IN"
LC_MONETARY="en_IN"
LC_MESSAGES="en_IN"
LC_PAPER="en_IN"
LC_NAME="en_IN"
LC_ADDRESS="en_IN"
LC_TELEPHONE="en_IN"
LC_MEASUREMENT="en_IN"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="en_IN"
LC_ALL=
dkb: ~ $ 


dkb: ~ $ locale charmap
UTF-8
dkb: ~ $
```

In the profile's *Preferences > Compatibility* I have Unicode---UTF-8.

---

I've tried with Inconsolata Medium, Noto Mono Regular, and Ubuntu Mono Regular. Same result: green asterisks.

Comment: gnome-terminal most definitely does support Unicode (UTF-8). What are your locale settings, what do `locale` and `locale charmap` report? (I get green ticks, by the way. Green stars if I force an old-fasioned 8-bit locale.)

Comment: Note that the ellipsis (three dots) shows up for you. If I force a Latin-x locale for `snap`, it still prints them in UTF-8, although the tick becomes a star. If I set my terminal's encoding to Latin-x accordingly, the ellipsis shows up broken. Whatever `snap` does is definitely fishy.

Comment: Hmmm, I can reproduce. `en_IN` results in this behavior (although its charset is UTF-8), while `en_IN.UTF-8` produces the tick symbol. Apparently `snap` checks for the locale definition string to contain the substring "UTF-8", rather than `locale charmap` (that is, `nl_langinfo(CODESET)`) being UTF-8. You should tell them that it's wrong. (Plus please also tell them that the way they handle the ellipsis is wrong, too.)

Comment: @egmont even `LANG=en_GB.utf8 snap list` works for me so if you post that as an answer I'll accept it.

Comment: Filed https://bugs.launchpad.net/snappy/+bug/1830051 and https://bugs.launchpad.net/snappy/+bug/1830052.

Comment: Thanks! Marked it "Affects me too".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like a [bug in snap](https://bugs.launchpad.net/snappy/+bug/1830051).

Switching the locale definition from `en_IN` to `en_IN.UTF-8` seems to be a workaround. This can probably done globally, and shouldn't change the behavior of proper apps since both locale identifiers refer to the same locale definition which uses UTF-8 encoding.